# How do I update all rows for a specific column in a DataTable using a C# function?

Tags: c#, datatable

```
foreach (var row in finalTable.Rows)
{
     //here I want to update the Date column from DateTime values to only Dates.           
}
```

Comment: -1, What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to reference a specific column to then assign it a value.

Comment: @Rj. Did you look at the documentation for the `DataRow` type to see what members it has, or what example usage is provided for it?

Comment: You can't change the date type of a column iterating the row. Reed's answer shows you stripping the time off. which is what you probably want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataRow.Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394.aspx) to fetch out a column as a specific type, and [`DataRow.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx) to set the new value.

For example, if you want to change the 3rd column:

```
foreach (var row in finalTable.Rows)
{
    DateTime? value = row.Field<DateTime?>(2);
    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        row[2] = value.Value.Day;
    }
}
```

Note that this requires a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and a `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` at the top of the .cs file.

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol field"

Comment: @Rj. Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`, and, at the top of your file, `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;`

Comment: Reed, that worked. However, when I try to do this: row[5] = value.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); ... the values are not changing in the DataTable.

Comment: @Rj. Why are you setting to a string, and not the actual DateTime (As I showed)

Answer (score 0):

```
row["rownumber"].date = new DateTime.Today;
```

is this what you mean ?

Comment: That will give three separate compiler errors.

Comment: obviously need fixes as you can see the question is very viage

Comment: No part of this answer will actually help him learn to use `DataRow`.